# Regex for matching and replacing "<" and ">"

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, regex-group

I need to split the following into multiple tokens in Spark Scala dataframe. Haven't used regex much earlier. Any help or direction would be good.

```
<c#><floating-point><type-conversion><double><decimal>
```

Expected output (each token in its own row):

```
c#
floating-point
type-conversion
double
decimal
```

I've tried the `<(.*?)>` but it gives me the following results. How can I ignore the tags

```
c#
<c#>
floating-point
<floating-point>
type-conversion
<type-conversion>
double
<double>
decimal
<decimal>
```

Comment: What is your exact expected output?

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself? code ?

Comment: @cchantep i need some direction to jump start...never done regex before. I googled and the info on regex is vast.

Comment: @cchantep tried some code but it returns partial results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying lookahead and lookbehind assertions should do the trick:

```
scala> val pattern = "(?<=<)(.*?)(?=>)".r
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?<=<)(.*?)(?=>)

scala> val s= "<c#><floating-point><type-conversion><double><decimal>"
s: String = <c#><floating-point><type-conversion><double><decimal>

scala> for { m <- pattern.findAllIn(s) } println(m)
c#
floating-point
type-conversion
double
decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we might want to simply design an expression to capture `<>` and replace with new lines, maybe this would work:

```
(?:\<|\>)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6H7olA/1)

```js
const regex = /(?:\<|\>)/gm;
const str = `<c#><floating-point><type-conversion><double><decimal>`;
const subst = `\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you could write `(?:\<|\>)` as `[<>]`